# What is the different between "hawq stop -M immediate" and "hawq stop -M fast"?

Tags: hawq

When I stop a HAWQ instance which is still connected to some sessions, it can not stop with "hawq stop -a".

```
$ hawq stop cluster -a
20160701:10:02:09:032804 hawq_stop:ChunlingdeMacBook-Pro:wangchunling-[INFO]:-Prepare to do 'hawq stop'
20160701:10:02:09:032804 hawq_stop:ChunlingdeMacBook-Pro:wangchunling-[INFO]:-You can find log in:
20160701:10:02:09:032804 hawq_stop:ChunlingdeMacBook-Pro:wangchunling-[INFO]:-/Users/wangchunling/hawqAdminLogs/hawq_stop_20160701.log
20160701:10:02:09:032804 hawq_stop:ChunlingdeMacBook-Pro:wangchunling-[INFO]:-GPHOME is set to:
20160701:10:02:09:032804 hawq_stop:ChunlingdeMacBook-Pro:wangchunling-[INFO]:-/usr/local/hawq
20160701:10:02:09:032804 hawq_stop:ChunlingdeMacBook-Pro:wangchunling-[INFO]:-Stop hawq with args: ['stop', 'cluster']
20160701:10:02:09:032804 hawq_stop:ChunlingdeMacBook-Pro:wangchunling-[INFO]:-No standby host configured
20160701:10:02:09:032804 hawq_stop:ChunlingdeMacBook-Pro:wangchunling-[INFO]:-Stop hawq cluster
20160701:10:02:09:032804 hawq_stop:ChunlingdeMacBook-Pro:wangchunling-[INFO]:-There are 1 connections to the database
20160701:10:02:09:032804 hawq_stop:ChunlingdeMacBook-Pro:wangchunling-[WARNING]:-There are other connections to this instance, shutdown mode smart aborted
20160701:10:02:09:032804 hawq_stop:ChunlingdeMacBook-Pro:wangchunling-[WARNING]:-Either remove connections, or use 'hawq stop master -M fast' or 'hawq stop master -M immediate'
20160701:10:02:09:032804 hawq_stop:ChunlingdeMacBook-Pro:wangchunling-[WARNING]:-See hawq stop --help for all options
20160701:10:02:09:032804 hawq_stop:ChunlingdeMacBook-Pro:wangchunling-[ERROR]:-Active connections. Aborting shutdown...
```

So what is the different between "hawq stop -M immediate" and "hawq stop -M fast"?

Answer (score 1):

-M fast

Fast shut down. Any transactions in progress are interrupted and rolled back.

-M immediate

Immediate shut down. Any transactions in progress are aborted. This mode kills all postgres processes without allowing the database server to complete transaction processing or clean up any temporary or in-process work files.

Here is the link of HAWQ documents:http://hdb.docs.pivotal.io/20/reference/cli/admin_utilities/hawqrestart.html

Answer (score 1):

Immediate shutdown is not recommended. Since in some instances, it can cause database corruption that requires manual recovery. You can refer to the documentation in the link http://hdb.docs.pivotal.io/20/reference/cli/admin_utilities/hawqrestart.html as @Wen Lin mentioned.

As an alternative, it is recommended that either use "hawq stop cluster -a -M fast" or use "pg_cancel_backend()" then do "hawq stop cluster -a".

Answer (score 1):

Internally, stop is just send signal to postgres process. Different stop modes means different signal.

smart mode: SIGTERM

fast mode: SIGINT

immediate mode: SIGQUIT